# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\sin (2 \pi nx)\, \mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{x}}dx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

Let's define the sequence 
$$
a_n=\int_0^1\sin (2 \pi nx)\, \mathrm{e}^{-x}dx.
$$ 
This sequence converges to $0$, as $n\to\infty$, and this could be shown using integration by parts.

Now I was thinking if the exponential is changed by $\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt x}$ if it still converges to 0. Which is true by Wolfram. But I couldn't come up with a proof.

Comment: To look it up in your textbook, see the index for "Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma".  Or find that on the Internet.  In place of $e^{-1}$ you can use any continuous function on $[0,1]$.  Of any Lebesgue integrable function.

Comment: @mudok $0$k. Erased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi n x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{x}}\,dx=0,
$$
let $\varepsilon>0$. Then integration by parts provides
$$
\int_{\varepsilon/2}^1 \sin(2\pi n x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{x}}\,dx=-\frac{\cos(2\pi n)-\cos(2\pi n \varepsilon)}{2\pi n}+\frac{1}{4\pi n}\int_{\varepsilon/2}^1 x^{-1/2}\cos(2\pi n x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{x}}\,dx,
$$
and hence
$$
\Big|\int_{\varepsilon/2}^1 \sin(2\pi n x)\Big|\le \frac{1}{\pi n}+\frac{1}{2\pi n}(1-\sqrt{\varepsilon}).
$$
Clearly, there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb N$, such that the left hand side of the above is less than $\varepsilon/2$, whenever $n\ge n_0$.

Thus, for $n\ge n_0$,
$$
\Big|\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi n x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{x}}\,dx\Big|\le
\Big|\int_0^\varepsilon \sin(2\pi n x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{x}}\,dx\Big|+
\Big|\int_\varepsilon^1 \sin(2\pi n x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{x}}\,dx\Big|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$

Comment: Is it true that the same argument would work for any function $f$ such that $F$ is bounded ($F'=f$).